# What is the Difference Between Recipient.Name and ExchangeUser.Name in Outlook Addin?

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, outlook-addin

There are these two objects:

1. `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.name)
2. `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExchangeUser` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.name)

And both of them have a name property that seems to be the same in my case and I can convert from `Recipient` to `ExchangeUser` using `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()`. Does it matter which `name` property I use? And what's the difference between the 2 (asides from the write/read differences from the docs).

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on Microsoft product line. But just from the naming, Outlook is a client and Exchange is a server.

That is to say, you can use Recipient object to refer to an addressee in your Outlook client, no matter what the actual mail server is, it can be Exchange, as in your case, or it can be Gmail, Yahoo! Mail, mail.live.com, whatever.

And the ExchangeUser object is specifically used for Exchange mailbox user, which is typically set up in enterprise. So you can find detailed properties like JobTitle and OfficeLocation (and a lot more) which the Recipient object doesn’t have.

> This object provides first-class access to properties applicable to Exchange users such as FirstName, JobTitle, LastName, and OfficeLocation.

Note that you cannot use Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser() if you are not connected to an Exchange server.

Answer (score 1):

Recipient object is stored inside the message itself as a row in the recipient table. `Recipient.Name` corresponds to `PR_DISPLAY_NAME`.
The `PR_ENTRYID` property in that row (present if the recipient is resolved) points to the address book object. That is what `Recipient.AddressEntry` returns - it uses recipient's `PR_ENTRYID` to call `IAddrBook::OpenEntry`.

The returned `AddressEntry.Name` can in theory be different from `Recipient.Name` (one comes from the address book object and another from `PR_DISPLAY_NAME` in the message recipient table). `ExchangeUser` is essentially an extension of the `AddressEntry` object with Exchange specific properties, so `ExchangeUser.Name` should be the same as `AddressEntry.Name`.

You can see this using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - select a message, go to the GetRecipientTable tab. Right lick on the `PR_ENTRYID` property and select `IMAPISession::OpenEntry`. You can also edit `PR_DISPLAY_NAME` property to something different from the GAL object. `PR_DISPLAY_TO` property on the message will reflect the new recipient name when the message is saved.